# Django REST - Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got {datatype}

Tags: django, rest, http, django-rest-framework

Using DRF I'm attempting a PUT request to update a file in my database.

I'm receiving the error seen in the title, exactly `Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got {datatype}.`.

The full body says this (`serializer.error_messages`):

```
{
    "required": "This field is required.",
    "null": "This field may not be null.",
    "invalid": "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got {datatype}."
}
```

I don't see any additional helpful information in the terminal, just this exactly.

My model is this:

```
from django.db import models

class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    upload_timestamp_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    upload_timestamp_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My serializer is this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import File

class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = '__all__'
```

My view so far is this:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@csrf_exempt
def file(request, file_id, format=None):
    try:
        data = File.objects.get(pk=file_id)
    except File.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = FileSerializer(data)
        return Response({'file': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = FileSerializer(data, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.error_messages, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

It comes down to the `is_valid()` call being false, with those error messages.

I know that a GET request returns data like this:

```
{
    "file": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "upload_timestamp_date": "2022-04-16",
        "upload_timestamp_time": "17:02:56.790144",
        "file": "https://files-learning.s3.amazonaws.com/akash_nemw.jpg"
    }
}
```

I have been submitting this data in the body (only changing the `name`):

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "testing change",
        "upload_timestamp_date": "2022-04-16",
        "upload_timestamp_time": "17:02:56.790144",
        "file": "https://files-learning.s3.amazonaws.com/akash_nemw.jpg"
}
```

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated, I have spent a day trying to figure out what is wrong with the submitted data.

Comment: I don't know what errors the `serializer.error_messages` field suppose to return. Usually, when you want to get validation errors from the serializer, you'd use `serializer.errors`. Could you change your code to return `serializer.errors` instead?

Comment: When request is `POST` you initialize your serializer with both `instance` and `data` parameters. Instead, you should only use `data` parameter `serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)`

Comment: @annonymous this didn't fix the problem unfortunately. I'm going off of the example in the docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#pulling-it-all-together

Comment: changing it to errors has pointed me in the right direction, thank you a lot @annonymous
my new error says "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form." which helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this (as suggested in a comment) was to replace `error_messages` with `errors`. I am unsure where I got the idea to use `error_messages`, but it was a small mistake leading to lots of frustration.

This lead to the error `The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.` I actually needed to define the request in the **form-data** section of Postman with the **file** drop down. This allowed me to choose a file from my computer instead of reusing the same S3 URL.

Comment: Good hint - had the same issue with `error_messages`, using `errors` instead solved it. I used it with `ser=MySerializer(data=obj_to_serialize)` and then `if ser.is_valid(raise_exception=False):  # ... data ok handling ... else: # ... error handling using ser.errors ...` to check first if the data is valid or not.